# "Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value."

Tags: reactjs, indexeddb

"Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': Evaluating the object store's key path did not yield a value."

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 const lenguageData = async (item) => {                    
    if (item === 1) {              
      await db.table("appSettings").put({messages:MensajesEspanol});         
    }else {            
      await db.table("appSettings").put({locale :"es-Es",messages:MensajesEspanol})        
    }            
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const lenguageData = async (item) => {
    if (item === 1) {
      await db.table("appSettings").put({key: 1});//debe agregarse un key para poder guardar un registro ya que no es auto-incrementable`introducir el código aquí`
    }else {
      console.log("entre2")

      await db.table("appSettings").put({locale :"es-Es",messages:MensajesEspanol})
    }
  };
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición de tu pregunta? Por favor, no olvides leer [ask], [answer] y hacer el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.